# Title may not fit into popup width on contact page

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, popups, contact

On [contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) in some cases the popup title may not fit into width because is covered by close button, e.g.:

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: I hope, this is fixed now. Screenshot from Mozilla Firefox 117.0.1 (64-bit), Windows 11 Pro  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZThwX.png

Comment: @Arulkumar unfortunately no, still an issue on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact)

Comment: seems to specifically happen somewhere between 500 and 650px width for me (regardless of height). Also breaks a bunch at < 420px (though it's fine if I'm on mobile (360px) so maybe this one doesn't matter)

Comment: Thanks for reporting, the issue seems to be with the close button and it's absolute position so it doesn’t affect layout and we don’t compensate for it. The bug is logged and will be assign to the appropriate team to fix.